# Как/Где хранить состояние авторизованного пользователя?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

У меня есть сайт с авторизацией. И когда пользователь вводит верный пароль мне нужно сохранять некоторую информацию о нём в виде объекта User. Сейчас это реализовано через конфигурацию:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Authorization(string Email, string Password)
{
    User CurrentUser = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == Email);
    if (CurrentUser != null && CurrentUser.Password == Password)
         Configuration["User"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(CurrentUser);  
    else
        return RedirectToAction("AuthorizationError", "Home");
    return RedirectToAction("List", "Articles");
}
```

Есть какой-нибудь другой способ или этот тоже нормальный?

Comment: возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону встроенные возможностей asp.net core https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1 там будет доступен пользователь через User или UserManager

Comment: Аутентификация и авторизация - это большииие топики, которые на двух пальцах не объяснишь. Рекомендую для изучения этот плейлист: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOeFnOV9YBa7dnrjpOG6lMpcyd7Wn7E8V